# Chrome extension for creating a unique ID

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I need a Chrome extension like this:

- Click on extension icon should create an unique ID
- Copy it to clipboard
- Write it in console

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "uniqID",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Generate uniqID",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "sw.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "clipboardWrite"
  ]
}
```

**sw.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log('test');
});
```

There is no error, but clicking on extension's icon - nothing happens.
Im expecting `test` in console

Also, I see `service worker (inactive)` a short time after loading extension

Please help

Comment: 1) Replace `browser_action` with `action`. 2) Due to the bug in Chrome you can't use navigator.clipboard in a service worker. Use document.execCommand in the offline document as shown in [the official example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write).

Comment: @wOxxOm - I replace `browser_action` with `action`. I also max simplify `sw.js` so just `console.log('test')` exists. Now there is no error but nothing happes, console i empty. See my post update, pls. Also service_worker becomes inactive, a short time after loading extension

Comment: 1) [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029), 2) Service worker isn't meant to be persistent, so it becoming inactive is the correct behavior.